# Using transient in a closure

Tags: clojure

I've tried to rewrite `memoize` for use on a single thread using transients instead of atoms to see if it is faster in my scenario but it works only for the first 8 calls. Why? Here is the code (Clojure 1.8):

```
(defn transient-memoize [f]
  (let [mem (transient {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (let [v (mem args ::none)]
        (if (= v ::none)
          (let [ret (apply f args)]
            (assoc! mem args ret)
            ret)
          v)))))

(defn slow-add [x y]
  (println "slow-add" x y)
  (Thread/sleep 10)
  (+ x y))

(defn call-add [memoizer]
  (let [f (memoizer slow-add)]
    (reduce +
            (for [i (range 10)
                  _ (range 2)]
              (f 100 i)))))

(call-add memoize)

slow-add 100 0
slow-add 100 1
slow-add 100 2
slow-add 100 3
slow-add 100 4
slow-add 100 5
slow-add 100 6
slow-add 100 7
slow-add 100 8
slow-add 100 9
=> 2090

(call-add transient-memoize)

slow-add 100 0
slow-add 100 1
slow-add 100 2
slow-add 100 3
slow-add 100 4
slow-add 100 5
slow-add 100 6
slow-add 100 7
slow-add 100 8
slow-add 100 8 ; <- called second time
slow-add 100 9
slow-add 100 9 ; <- called second time
=> 2090
```

**UPDATE**

It does work if I initialize the transient map so it is a `TransientHashMap` instead of `TransientArrayMap`. It appears as if transient map, unlike normal map, does not auto convert from `ArrayMap` to `HashMap` as collection grows. Is that always the case?

```
(defn transient-memoize [f]
  (let [mem (transient (hash-map ::force-hash-map ::force-hash-map))]
    (fn [& args]
      (let [v (mem args ::none)]
        (if (= v ::none)
          (let [ret (apply f args)]
            (assoc! mem args ret)
            ret)
          v)))))
```

Comment: What are you expecting that you aren't seeing?

Comment: `slow-add` should be called only once for given arguments but calls with `100 8` and `100 9` are repeated (see the output above).

Comment: Functions over transients behave the same as functions over persistent data structures: they take transient as argument, modify it, and return transient. You should continue to work on returned transient, as transient might change under the hood (performance reasons, or otherwise). When you call (assoc! mem args ret), returned transient might be something else than mem (but still transient). But you cannot assign returned transient to map, as let var is constant. This is why ref vars, such as atoms are used (maybe you could use volatile, with transients: (let [mem (volatile (transient {}))]

Comment: I disagree that this question is an "exact duplicate" of the linked question.  While they certainly are similar, I believe they have significant, material differences.  For example, this question does not have a loop that can be used to re-bind the transient to a new value.  So while the root cause (you cannot rely on in-place mutation of variables bound to transients) is the same, the solution (rebind the loop variable) does not apply in this case.